# Django rest framework create object with many-to-many filed serializer

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, orm

I can't create a project object with many-to-many field to languages model. I need to find the best way to implement this. I have tried the [django rest framework docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writing-create-methods-for-nested-representations), but it didn't work for me. Do the language objects need to be created before the project object or DRF will handle this? This problem occurs when I added the owner field, then I needed to add the create method inside the ProjectSerializer to save the object owner, but then this error occurred: `Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use languages.set() instead.`
I tried `languages.set()` but it still does not work.

models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Language(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    description = models.TextField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Developer(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    age = models.IntegerField()
    bio = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Project(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    stars = models.IntegerField()
    developer = models.ForeignKey(Developer, related_name='projects', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['stars']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

serializers.py

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

from developers.models import Language, Developer, Project


class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'stars', 'developer', 'languages', 'owner', ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        project = Project.objects.create(owner=self.context['request'].user, **validated_data)
        return project


class LanguageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    projects = ProjectSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Language
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'projects', 'owner', ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
         language = Language.objects.create(owner=self.context['request'].user, **validated_data)
         return language


class DeveloperSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    projects = ProjectSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Developer
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'age', 'bio', 'projects', 'owner', ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
         developer = Developer.objects.create(owner=self.context['request'].user, **validated_data)
         return developer
```

Comment: You can not directly add ManyToMany field. Before adding `languages` field, Your Project object needs to be created. Try this `languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language, blank=True)` and then in create method, you can add ManyToMany field once the object of project is created.

Comment: can you show me how i add the many to many field in create method, do have to iterate over language objects?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) to get an idea how to do this. Inside create, call [set](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.set) on your m2m fields

Comment: it throw this error ```django.db.models.manager.BaseManager._get_queryset_methods.<locals>.create_method.<locals>.manager_method() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list``` but why i need to create new language object evey time i create new project ?

Comment: is it man-to-many field allow me to use language object with other projects too ?